# mac status bar application not working

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm following this: http://lepture.com/en/2012/create-a-statusbar-app simple tutorial to get a Status Bar based Mac app working, I've referenced Apple's NSStatusItem class reference as well - And cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong?

It's just not working. My project uses ARC.

Here's FPAppDelete.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface FPAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSMenu *statusMenu;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSStatusItem *statusBar;

@end
```

Here's FPAppDelegate.m:

```
#import "FPAppDelegate.h"

@implementation FPAppDelegate
@synthesize statusBar = _statusBar;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
}

- (void) awakeFromNib {
    self.statusBar = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength];

    self.statusBar.title = @"G";

    self.statusBar.menu = self.statusMenu;
    self.statusBar.highlightMode = YES;
}

@end
```

I'm not expecting this at all, but I get this when I run the app, **with nothing in my Status Bar**

Comment: Before claiming that your status bar is not working, you should know what the status bar is in the first place. I don't know even know why you put your code in the awakFromNib method of the AppDelegate file.

Comment: If you know what the status bar does, what's the point of your showing a screenshot of the application window, then?

Comment: @ElTomato The point was to show what I'm getting. (I've removed the image from my question, considering it was getting confusing for everyone)

Comment: @ElTomato to your earlier comment about code being in the `awakeFromNib` method, I have it there because that's where most of the tutorials I'm following are putting it. I'm not an Objective-C ninja and an extreme n00b at Obj-c and trying to learn it, So will appreciate any and all help I can get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are willing to listen.  So I'll show you quickly how to run a status application.

(1) Add NSMenu to the side bar (or whatever you call).  (See the screenshot below.)  It's up to you to keep or remove 3 generic menu items.

[image]

(2) Add the following instance variables under AppDelegate.h.

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    IBOutlet NSMenu *statusMenu;
    NSStatusItem *statusItem;
    NSImage *statusImage;
}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (strong) NSMenuItem *menuItem1; // show application
```

I'll also add a property as an example.

The following code is for AppDelegate.m

```
@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize menuItem1;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    [self setMainStatus];
}

- (void)setMainStatus {    
    statusItem = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength];
    statusImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"statusImage"];
    [statusItem setImage:statusImage];
    [statusItem setMenu:statusMenu];

    NSMutableString *menuname1 = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:NSLocalizedString(@"statusMenuShowApplication", @"Show Application Window")];
    menuItem1 = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:menuname1 action:@selector(statusApplicatinClicked:) keyEquivalent:@""];
    [statusMenu addItem:menuItem1];
}

- (void)statusApplicatinClicked:(id)sender {
    [self.window setIsVisible:YES]; 
}

@end
```

(3) Go back to Interface Builder and connect Status Menu to the NSMenu control you've added.

The setMainStatus method (or whatever you want to name) adds menu items to the status menu programatically.  First, you need to create NSStatusbar, which takes NSImage.  This NSImage is used to show an icon on the status menu.  Next, add menu items and separators to the status menu (status Menu in my case).  I have menuItem1 as a property so that the application could enable/disable it.  That's just a quick example.  You can add NSView to the status menu.  If you want to add a separator, it can go as follows.

```
 [statusMenu addItem:[NSMenuItem separatorItem]];
```

You don't need an application window to run a status menu application.  You have to show the main application window for the first time if you are going to submit your status application to Apple's Mac App Store, though.

Comment: wow! thank you very much for this, I guess I was always listening :) I created a new project and followed your instructions. And noticed something weird, I put a `NSLog` statement in my `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method and surprisingly it's not being invoked at all. I read somewhere I need to connect `Application's` delegate outlet to my `AppDelegate` I did that too but the method is still not being invoked. I think this is the root of the problem.

Comment: I'm using Xcode 5.0.2, not sure if version mismatch might cause an issue?

Comment: PS: Also, I'm still getting the same window I was getting earlier. :/

Comment: Finally got it working. Your instructions worked, I was just using a transparent png which was not showing up and I had to click over the Status bar to reveal the dropdown. Thanks!

Comment: Wondering why in your code you have this bit repeated twice: `statusItem = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength];
    statusImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"statusImage"];
    [statusItem setImage:statusImage];
    [statusItem setMenu:statusMenu];`

Answer (score 0):

The status bar is the top-right part of your entire *screen*. It's where the date and time, Spotlight, etc live in the Menu Bar.

The screenshot you posted is of the *title bar* of your primary `NSWindow`.

Comment: Yes, I posted this screenshot because this is what i get instead of the G in my status bar?

Comment: @JasdeepSingh you get an `NSWindow` because that's what you have in your `MainMenu.xib` file.

Comment: I even removed the Window from my MainMenu.xib, still the same.